# How to increase the padding around a plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a horizontal barchart, with too-tight padding:

```
data <- data.frame(month = factor(c("Nov", "Dec", "Jan", "Feb")),
                   count = c(1489, 788, 823, 1002))

g <- (ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes(x=month, y=count)) +
        ggplot2::geom_col() +
        ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(limits=rev(data$month)) +
        ggplot2::coord_flip()) +

g
```

[image: horizontal barchart with too-tight padding]

I am happy with the spacing between the bars, but I want a lot more space all around the 4-bar stack.  In other words, I want more padding around the central 4-bar figure.  The area of the light-gray rectangle that serves as the background for the 4-bar stack should remain unchanged, but the size of the 4-bar stack within that rectangle should shrink, with the net effect of produing wider padding all around the 4-bar stack; in other words, more of the light-gray background will be visible around the 4-bar stack.

Also, I am looking for ways to do this that are entirely independent of the actual values on the axes.  The code should produce the same visual effect whether the x-range is 0-1500 or 0-1500000 or altogether non-numeric (i.e. categorical).

This means that the extra padding must be specified either (a) as percentages for the figure's total width and height; or (b) fixed numbers of pixels; or (c) fixed units of measurement (cm, inches, printer points, etc.).

Lastly, *ideally*, I would like to be able to specify the padding for all four edges independently.

How can I do this?

**IMPORTANT**  I don't want to increase the *margins* around the light gray background.  I want to increase the *padding within* the light gray background.  If this distinction is not clear, please see [this](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-margin-and-vs-padding/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `expand_scale` function within the `expand` argument to `scale_x_continuous`-type functions. It's a bit wordy, but...

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=month,y=count)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    scale_x_discrete(limits=(data$month), expand=expand_scale(mult=c(0.5,0.5))) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=count), hjust=-0.3) +
    coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(expand=expand_scale(mult=c(0.5,0.5)))
```

Play around with the two elements of the `mult` vector, which define the padding above and below the axis, so you can change each side of the plot independently (although it's not exactly transparent, and will take some fiddling). See `?expand_scale` for more info.

[image]